# Is the message box in tkinter only limited to displaying letters?

Tags: python, tkinter

If not, then how do i display the result of 2*(l+b) as show in the following code?

```
def answer():
      w = messagebox.showinfo("your answer", 2*(l+b))
      w.pack(side = RIGHT)

   button = Button(t1, text = "answer", command = answer)
   button.pack(side = RIGHT)
```

Comment: no its not limitted on letters, what you are getting?

Comment: im getting a blank information box

Comment: The indentation in your code is broken. It's not clear if the button is inside or outside of `answer`.

Comment: The button is outside the function, will fix indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message box can indeed show numerical values (converted to strings).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def answer():
    l = 2
    b = 5
    w = messagebox.showinfo("your answer", 2*(l+b))

t1 = Tk()
button = Button(t1, text = "answer", command = answer)
button.pack(side = RIGHT)
t1.mainloop()
```

Running this code and clicking "answer" will bring up a messagebox showing "14".